# Entity Framework - One to One relationship, how to save record

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a one-to-one relationship on two tables with are represented by 2 classes in my EDM.

I am trying to save a new record and am confused how to save to the second entity.  I have tried the following.

```
Dim myObject as new MyObject

myObject.prop1 = 5
myObject.prop2 = "Test"

myObject.myOtherObject.prop1 = 3
myObject.myOtherObject.prop2 = "Hello"
```

But I get an error when I hit `myObject.myOtherObject.prop1 = 3` because `myOtherObject` hasn't been initialized.

How do I initialize an child object under `myObject`?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Dim myObject as new MyObject

myObject.prop1 = 5
myObject.prop2 = "Test"

myObject.myOtherObject = new MyOtherObject
myObject.myOtherObject.prop1 = 3
myObject.myOtherObject.prop2 = "Hello"
```