# Entity Framework One-To-One Relationship Form Edit/Save

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

- I have a domain class called Bar which has a bunch of properties
- One of the properties Bar has is actually another domain class called Address which is of type Address.
- Address has a **one to one** relationship with Bar. So one Bar has one address and one address has one bar.
- Due to this, I have *both domain classes* set to use BarId as their primary key.
- Per the [Microsoft Virtual Academy instructors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJ4YyZJ9qi8&feature=youtu.be#), in order for EF to understand this, you have to specify the primary key with both the [Key] attribute, as well as the [ForeignKey] attribute. They also say you have to declare the property types as virtual, as I have done. See here:
  **Address Domain Model:**

  ```
  public class Address
  {
      [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "Must be a number")]
      public int? Number { get; set; }
      public string StreetName { get; set; }

      public string City { get; set; }

      public string State { get; set; }
      [Required]

      public int ZipCode { get; set; }

      public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
      [Key]
      [ForeignKey("Bar")]
      public int BarId { get; set; }
  }
  ```

**BAR Domain Model:**

```
 public class Bar
    {
        public int BarId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string GooglePlaceId { get; set; }
        public string SundayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string MondayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string TuesdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string WednesdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string ThursdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string FridayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public string SaturdayDiscounts { get; set; }
        public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Last Updated")]
        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
```

Last but not least, this is the view model that I am using:

```
{
    public class BarFormViewModel
    {
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public Bar Bar { get; set; }

        public bool IsNew { get; set; }


    }
}
```

My question is, **how do I properly implement this into a form logic so that the address can be edited when the bar is edited?** I am getting thrown off because the Bar domain has an Address which means **I can tell my form to update either Address.StreetName or I can tell my form to update Bar.Address.StreetName where the Address.BarId == the bar.BarId.** Likewise, I can select an Address object from the database and pass it to my form (via viewmodel), *or* I can select just a bar and then pass my view bar.Address. Is there any difference between doing these two things? So far my form works but the data passed through the viewmodel, into the form and back, isn't actually saving into the database. All data that is *not* passed to the viewmodel and through the form is saving just fine.
Here are my edit and save actions for reference:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {

            var bar = _context.Bars.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BarId == id);
            //Make sure that the id actually exists:
            if (bar == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            var viewModel = new BarFormViewModel
            {
                Address = bar.Address,
                Bar = bar,
                IsNew = false
            };


            return View("BarForm", viewModel);
        }
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Save(Bar bar)
        {

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var viewModel = Mapper.Map<Bar, BarFormViewModel>(bar);
                viewModel.IsNew = false;
                return View("BarForm", viewModel);

            }
            if (bar.BarId == 0)
            {


                bar.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;
                _context.Bars.Add(bar);

            }
            else
            {
                var barInDb = _context.Bars.Single(b => b.BarId == bar.BarId);
             //   var addressInDb = _context.Addresses.Single(a => a.BarId == bar.Bar.Address.BarId);
                Mapper.Map(bar, barInDb);
                barInDb.MondayDiscounts = bar.MondayDiscounts;
                barInDb.LastUpdated = DateTime.UtcNow;

            }
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Bar");
        }
```

I have taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451648/entity-framework-one-to-one-relationship-how-to-save-record), however, this does not seem to be the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you missing with your current database design is `Identify each set of related data with a primary key` in `First Normal Form` on `database normalization rules` (check [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/kb/283878)). If you have one primary key, why not make them just one table? It will be much faster and easy to maintain.

But I think since `Bar` and `Address` are different things in their nature, so it is better to have two tables with different primary key. Then add `BarId` to `Address` table and `public virtual Address Address` to `Bar` table. So you will have a main `Bar` object and associated `Address` object.

Then `Entity Framework` will do the rest!: If you don't have current Address object for your current Bar , It will create it , if you change related address details on bar and try to update bar, EF will update Address too.

Please also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38174769/3743442) for getting some ideas how EF handles associated objects.